# How to use TinyFCK in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I'm working with Ruby on Rails 2.3.8, and I would like to upload images into the post's text editor (kind of a blog application).

I've read about TinyFCK, and I've tried to make it work. I've also downloaded the "simplebrowser" plugin for this editor.

I placed the following code in my view:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'tinyfck/tiny_mce.js' %>

<script type="text/javascript">

tinyMCE.init({
       mode : "textareas",
       plugins : "simplebrowser",
       plugin_simplebrowser_width : '800', //default
       plugin_simplebrowser_height : '600', //default
       plugin_simplebrowser_browseimageurl : '../../plugins/simplebrowser/browser.html?Type=Image&Connector=connectors/php/connector.php'
   });
</script>

<h1>New post</h1>

<% form_for @post, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Body' %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body, :class => "mceEditor" %>

  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

When I click on the "Upload image" icon, I can see a "browse" button. When I click it, a popup will open asking for the file to upload. After I pick one and click the "Upload" button, it stop working without any message, and the image does not get uploaded.

Does anybody know how to make this work?

Thanks in advance.